# vertices locking in mirror

Tags: vertices

I am modelling a car.So there is a edge loop as highlighted in image.When i move the vertices of that loop about x,y, or z axis ,the vertice gets locked to x=0 mm and then it does not move about x axis.I first thought it is happening due to clipping but still it's happening. I am attaching the images..plz help me sort it out.[image]

Comment: Did you uncheck "Clipping" in the mirror modifier ? Because in your picture it is still checked

Comment: oh yes after removing the clipping it's isn't happening but there is another problem i m not able to overcome.you see the centre from where clipping starts,that particular edge loop is not moving about x axis.it seems to be locked. it moves only if i do it from vertices transform option.it is locked at x=0m.

Comment: Does it move when you disable the shrinkwrap modifiers ?